# warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (Debug\) contains files shared from another project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, c++-cli

I'm working on C++\CLI that someone else started. The solution is made up of 3 C projects and 1 C++\CLI project that uses them.
I've duplicated the C++\CLI project and change it name and ProjectGUID property in the vcxproj file.

The problem is I still get the error listed bellow.

How can I fix this?

`Warning  1   warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (Debug\) contains files shared from another project (my_project.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   388 5   seebo_prod_line_tool`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. If you copied the whole project, including Debug dir, than kill the intermediate directory and try rebuilding. If the problem still persists, ensure your $(IntDir) properties point to separate locations for each project and each configuration/platform combination.

Answer (score 50):

Same problem here, solved by

1. Deleting *all* `Debug\` and `Release\` folders (there were more of them in subfolders where I didn't expect them)
2. Changing the `.sln` file manually to fix the name of a referenced C++ project (`.vcxproj`) which apparently was not renamed when renaming the project in Visual Studio

Answer (score 15):

My suggestion is to make sure the intermediate directory for each project is different (as suggested by someone else earlier.)

To do this,

- Open the project's Properties dialog
- Under Configuration Properties, select General
- Make sure the Intermediate Directory for this project is unique to this project.

I ran into this problem because using previous versions of Developer Studio I had a host of companion projects but wanted all of them to put their output in a common "Release" folder.  Inadvertently I had set the same common release folder settings in the Intermediate Directory path for some of the projects (but not all).

Comment: On top of that, I had to "Clean" the project for all configurations, removed the lingering folders from previous builds and it worked. Thank you Gixxernaut!

Answer (score 11):

I found you can disable these types of warnings by added the following to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IntDirSharingDetected>
    None
  </IntDirSharingDetected>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Disabling the warning unfortunately does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  I'm making a set of vcxproj files to match a bunch of CPP testing files, each of which has its own `main`, but intentionally share a master common settings file (each vcxproj is just a stub) *and* use one set of intermediate directories so I don't make a new directory for every file.  I know, the file names need to be distinct.  Now stop warning me or confusing my downstream user.

Comment: This is not always a problem, sometimes you may want to have things set up that way, and for valid reasons. Thank you for providing this info!

Answer (score 7):

I myself also encountered this kind of warning.. But I obtained this in a different situation, I renamed my whole solution/project via IDE and thus making another copy of an entirely different project. So what I have here is a total of two projects sharing one common resource, source and header files. This makes this warning pop up.

I fixed this by deleting the files associated with the project, which you renamed previously. Delete these INSIDE the DEBUG folder. In your case, try deleting all 'my_project' files, regardless of any file extensions because it shares resource files to your duplicated project.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of this problem is copying an intermediate directory that was created by Visual Studio, and that already contains files from a previous build. It is not a problem in the project settings, but a problem caused by the existence of unexpected files from another project. In this context the warning is benign, but annoying.

The minimal solution is to find and delete each such file. The simpler solution is usually to "super clean": delete every directory created by Visual Studio (with names like bin, obj, x64, x86, Debug, Release and so on), and allow VS to re-create them during the normal build process.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem as well, and for me, the cause was that there were multiple `libname.tlog` directories inside the intermediate build folder.  These directories contain `libname.lastbuildstate` files that I assume are used for dependency checking.  Doing a Clean of the project I don't think will delete these extra directories.

So in this case I was able to delete the `libname.tlog` directories and build again.  I don't know how it got into the state of having multiple directories inside each intermediate directory -- perhaps they were created when I updated the VS version.